# Given the first and second derivatives, determine whether it is an local extrmum

Tags: calculus

If $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)\neq0$, does it mean that function $f$ has a local extremum in $x$?
If $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)=0$, does it mean that function $f$ has no local extremum in $x$?

Comment: Why don't you start with some examples like $f(x) = x^2 ; x^3$ which may gives you some insight into a more formal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)\neq0$, then there is a local extremum in $x$.  When $f''(x)=0$, there is a horizontal slope and an inflection point, and not necessarily an extremum.  Think of $f(x)=x^3$.  As @DavidMitra points out in the comment below, this reasoning applies only to odd powers.  For even powers, there is a local extremum.

For surfaces in two dimensions, places where the gradient vanishes, as well in places where either the second partial derivatives vanish or a matrix of second derivatives (known as a Hessian) is indefinite is called a [saddle point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point).

Comment: What about $f(x)=x^4$? This does not have an inflection point at $x=0$, it does have an extremum at $x=0$, yet $f'(x)=f''(x)=0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: In my haste, I did not add that my reasoning applies only to odd powers.  Thanks.